# Не могу настроить сервер Cherrypy python для приема уведомлений от юmoney

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, http-status-code-500, cherrypy

Хотел написать для себя телеграм бота, который оповещает об успешном переводе на мой кошелёк юmoney.

Бот сформирован, все хорошо работает, вебхук исправен и отзывается. Но вот в чём проблема: при получении POST запроса от юmoney я получаю `415` или `500` ошибку `HTTP`, я новичок, использовав возможности всемогущего Google я понял что вся проблема в том что я не смог правильно настроить сервер cherrypy на прием `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` по этому прошу помощи, т.к. ни в официальной литературе ни в поиске Google ничего не нашёл для решения своей проблемы.

Описание запроса от юmoney:

```
метод — POST;
каждый параметр уведомления указывается парой ключ/значение в виде параметра POST-запроса;
MIME-тип — application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
кодировка символов — UTF‑8.
```

Буду благодарен за помощь. В коде присуцтвуют:

```
cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Функция для обработки входящего запроса:

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.config(**{'tools.cors.on': True,
            'tools.decode.on': True,
            'tools.decode.default_encoding': ['utf-8'],
        })
@cherrypy.tools.json_in()
def test(self):
    tempData = self.data
    print(tempData)
    return ''
```

В таком случае ответ:

```
    HTTP Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 638, in respond
    self._do_respond(path_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 674, in _do_respond
    self.namespaces(self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cherrypy/lib/reprconf.py", line 89, in __call__
    exit(None, None, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cptools.py", line 453, in __exit__
    tool = getattr(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Toolbox' object has no attribute 'cors'
[28/Feb/2021:12:45:12] HTTP
Request Headers:
  Remote-Addr: 77.75.153.75
  HOST: мой.хост
  ACCEPT: */*
  USER-AGENT: AHC/2.1
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  Content-Length: 262
77.75.153.75 - - [28/Feb/2021:12:45:12] "POST /1653147044:AAGIOIThReiNVimGU5aUvObD96lC-OH3RCM/test HTTP/1.1" 500 1416 "" "AHC/2.1"
```

Ответ от моего сервера если убрать `'tools.cors.on': True,`:

```
"POST my.adress HTTP/1.1" 415 1544 "" "AHC/2.1"
```